# Exibir sequencia de datas automáticas

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

Galera tenho uma dúvida em relação ao Datagridview:

Estou fazendo um sistema de folha de pagamento, nesse sistema eu tenho que trazer o primeiro dia do lançamento e o dia final.
O problema é que, por exemplo, eu preciso fazer um sistema em que a cada vez que ele apertar o botao "gravar" ele pegue a data inicial e a cada nova linha ele gere o dia seguinte:

Exemplo

```
linha[0] = 10/03/2018

linha[1] = 11/03/2018

linha[n] = ...
```

É possível fazer isso de maneira automática?

Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: O preenchimento automático é abaixo da data]

Favor ignorar os campos de entrada e as caixas de seleção.

Grato desde já

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal consegui resolver, deixarei o código aqui caso seja útil para alguém:

```
    private void Gravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

   //evento para inserir a data no datagridview
   //ao inves de pegar a data atual ele pega o valor do datetime picker

            var culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR"); //setar culture em portugues para traduzir dia da semana

            DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.Now;//pega data atual

            string diaDaSemanaAtual = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(dataAtual.DayOfWeek).ToString();
            string somenteDataTexto = dataAtual.ToShortDateString();//pega somente a parte da data para ser mostrada

            //se possui itens no grid, atualiza a "dataAtual"
            if (DataGridColaboradores.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                var ultimaLinha = DataGridColaboradores.Rows[DataGridColaboradores.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                dataAtual = Convert.ToDateTime(ultimaLinha);
                DateTime dataMaisUm = dataAtual.AddDays(1);
                diaDaSemanaAtual = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(dataMaisUm.DayOfWeek).ToString();
                somenteDataTexto = dataMaisUm.ToShortDateString();
            }


            DataGridColaboradores.Rows.Add(
                somenteDataTexto,
                diaDaSemanaAtual,
                textBoxEntrada.Text,
                textBoxSaida.Text,
                textBoxEntrada2.Text,
                textBoxSaida2.Text
            );
}
```